# Java Implementing Comparable

Tags: java, sorting, compareto

I am trying to overwrite the compareTo in Java such that it works as follows. There will be two string arrays containing k strings each. The compareTo method will go through the words in order, comparing the kth element of each array. The arrays will then be sorted thusly. The code I have currently is as follows, but it does not work properly.

I need a return statement outside the for-loop. I'm not sure what this return statement should return, since one of the for-loop return statements will always be reached.

Also, am I using `continue` correctly here?

```
public int compareTo(WordNgram wg) {
    for (int k = 0; k < (this.myWords).length; k++) {
        String temp1 = (this.myWords)[k];
        String temp2 = (wg.myWords)[k];
        int last = temp1.compareTo(temp2);
        if (last == 0) {
            continue;
        } else {
            return last;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it not work properly? Exception? Doesn't sort as you would like?

Comment: "*it does not work properly*" does not help much. Why doesn't it work? How do you test it? Can you show [a simple but complete example that reproduces the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? etc.

Comment: Well the first problem I am running into is that I need a return statement outside the for-loop. I'm not sure what this return statement should return, since one of the for-loop return statements will always be reached.

Comment: Also, am I using 'continue' correctly here?

Comment: Yes, you do need a return outside the loop... what happens if all the words are the same?

Comment: What you want is not clear. Clarify it.

Comment: If all words are the same then I would return 0 since the two arrays are considered to be equal. So should I just add a return 0 statement outside the for-loop then?

Comment: Off-Topic: Wondered for 10 seconds what kind of framework "compareto" is :D

Comment: Why not simply do something like `return Arrays.toString(myWords).compareTo(Arrays.toString(other.myWords))` which will compare the whole concatenated String?

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare the two string at the same location:

```
int last = temp1.compare(temp2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java compiler mandates all the end points must have a return statement. In your case you must return 0 at end so when both arrays contain completely equal strings the caller will know they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You should start listening to your compiler, because after looking at your code for 1 minute, I spotted two undefined states: `this.myWords.length` is `0` and the two words are equal.

Also, I personally find it very difficult to handle multiple method exit points with all possibilities for input considered and rather insert a single returning statement which makes debugging easier and the results more predictable. In your case for example, I would collect the results of `compareTo` in a collection if they differ from `0` so that after the for-loop has finished, you could decide at the state of this collection if `0` (empty collection) or the first value in the collection could be returned. I like this more formal approach, because it enforces you to think set-like as in "Give me all comparing results where `compareTo` results in anything else but `0`. If this list is empty, the comparing result is `0`, otherwise it is the first element of the list."